# NSTableView : Can I lazily fetch subsets of the table datasource?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Can I lazily fetch subsets of the NSTableView datasource?
So that I don't need to load my entire database in memory? So that when the table scrolls, the app is accessing to core data again.

At the moment I've only figured out how to enable/disable lazy fetching for the *entire* datasource. But I would like to know if there is a way to split the fetching in different runs".

Comment: yes you can. When you do your core data fetch you can specify an `Offset`. That coupled with a fetch limit means you have yourself a fetch range. When the tableview shows the last fetched object, go ahead and use the count as the offset, and get the next set of entities (20, 50, whatever your preference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a core data fetch you can specify an `Offset`. An offset coupled with a `fetch limit` gives you a range. When your tableview scrolls to the last object, do another fetch and specify your current count as the offset, and your preferred limit.

Comment: Ok. And what if the data is bounded to a NSTreeController (so that I don't have an explicit NSFetchRequest with fetchOffset attribute?

Answer (score 1):

My favorite approach in this case is following.

I keep array of loaded records in my controller. At viewDidLoad this array contains zero elements. Then i request first portions of records from database (restricted by fetch limit of 50 records for example). After records fetched I put them into this array. Also a store a flag indicating is all records loaded or not.

In my table view i always display all records from my array. If not all records loaded then I add one cell with activity indicator. When user scrolls table view down to the cell with activity indicator I request loading of next portion of records from database (using offset and fetch limit again). After records loaded I add them to my array, update flag and call reloadData on my tableView.

Two main methods of my tableViewDataSource looks like:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.allDataLoaded?self.dataArray.count?self.dataArray.count+1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row>=self.dataArray.count) {
        // indicator cell
        [self requestReadNext];
        UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"IndicatorCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    } else {
        MyCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        MyObject* obj=[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self fillCell:cell withObject:obj];
        return cell;
    }
}
```